# Siamese Network with RGB images

Tags: deep-learning, caffe

I tried following the Siamese Network MNIST example with Caffe, and many other stackoverflow posts, or here on Google groups, but the information is always incomplete or a dead end. All I am trying to do is to feed a siamese network 2 RGB images to calculate for similarity.

What I've done so far is that I concatenated the 2 RGB images into one, converted it to leveldb, edited the slicing layer in "mnist_siamese_train_test.prototxt" to "slice_point: 3". From what I understand now is that the problem will be with the channels. How do I fix this issue, I havent found any useful resource to tell me how to do this, or fits my case. Please let me know if there is another way totally of just feeding the network directories and lists instead of leveldb and concatenating the images. Let me know if there is anything that needs further explanation.

Comment: what exactly is the problem with the channels? it seems like you are doing the right thing here. What **exactly** is the problem?

Comment: BTW, instead of using the Siamese approach, have you considered the "minibatch loss" appraoch of [Wexler et al](https://arxiv.org/abs/1605.07270)?

Answer (score 0):

you can find the answer in details in [this thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/caffe-users/SOgOkPYps1g), in short, you have two options:

1. Use a slice layer to slice the blob you created in the lmdb, as you pointed in the question, you have slice_point:3 and a 6 "channel" image (3 for each image) it should split it in 2 images with 3 channels each.
2. Use 2 different InputDataLayers, each one with a different file, you can see a working example in the thread.

Now, as pointed out, you seem to be doing the right thing, can you copy-paste your error and your .prototxt file here?
Also check if the dimension along which you are slicing is correct